The transcendence degree of fraction fields
I am trying to prove the following statement: Let $p$ be a prime ideal of domain $R$ and $k \subset R$, $K = Frac(R), K' = Frac(R / p)$ be the quotient fields, then $tr.deg_k(K') \le tr.deg_k(K)$ and the equality holds exactly when $p = 0$.
I originally come up with this question when I am trying to prove $\dim V \le \dim U$ if $V, U$ are closed subvarieties of $\mathbb{A}^n$ and $V \subset U$. I know that there are other equivalent definitions of dimension which are much easier to use than this one. But I want to stick with this definition since it is the one used by Fulton's book.
The major difficulty I met is that I cannot associate elements in $K$ with elements in $K'$. This is because $f / g \in K$ may have $g \in p$ and therefore there is no corresponding elements in $K'$.
